# Cron job doesn't execute the shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I want to create a shell script which will be run every minute by cron job. Script's job will be to notify me to (un)plug the charger in different conditions:

1. when battery state is charging and it is around 80% full, it reminds me to unplug the cable.
2. when battery state is discharging and it is around 40% full, it reminds me to plug the cable back.

My crontab file:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

* * * * * /home/aleksa/charge.sh
# newline
```

My `/home/aleksa/charge.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

RESPONSE="$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0)"

#if percentage is around 40%, and state is discharging
if echo "${RESPONSE}" | grep -E '38%|39%|40%|41%|42%' && echo "${RESPONSE}" | grep -w 'discharging'
then zenity --notification --window-icon=update.png --text "Connect charger"; 
fi

#if percentage is around 80%, and state is charging
if echo "${RESPONSE}" | grep -E '78%|79%|80%|81%|82%' && echo "${RESPONSE}" | grep -w 'charging'
then zenity --notification --window-icon=update.png --text "Disconnect charger"; 
fi
```

I think that problem is in the script because I have tried different things in order to detect where the problem is:

1. script works when it is executed independently of the cron
2. cron job works - I have tested it by appending `date` command response to a file every minute
3. I have tried without declaring `RESPONSE` variable, and it still doesn't work

Comment: Is that a legal `crontab` file on your OS?  Also, this question is likely off-topic as it's about `crontab` configuration and is likely better on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, its legal, I omitted rest of the file. and thanks for downvote (if thats you).

Comment: Is your script executable? is the crontab user the same as has permissions? does crontab work for other things, like `date>/tmp/proof`?

Comment: @PaulHodges 'Is your script executable' -> Yes, it is. 'does crontab work for other things, like date>/tmp/proof? ' -> it does, I wrote details in question

Comment: Is there a log?

Answer (score 1):

Set your *$DISPLAY* variable before calling Zenity.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

[Understanding linux DISPLAY variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20947681/1028589)